# map through array and return all matches mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i want to map through array of Object that saved on `MongoDB Database` and return all indexes that matches with my condition...

for example, here is the the array..

```
orders: [
      {
        foodId: {
          type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: "Foods",
        },
        placeId: {
          type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
          required: true,
          ref: "Places",
        },
        qty: {
          type: Number,
          required: true,
          default: 1,
        },
        price: {
          type: Number,
          required: true,
        },
      },
    ],
```

i want to get all foods that orders from a place, i tried this query but didn't work and its only return first match and ignore rest of them.

```
//   HERE IS ORDERS COLLECTION, NOT ORDERS ARRAY THAT CONTAINS OBJECTS
    const order = await Orders.find({

//   HERE IS ORDERS ARRAY THAT CONTAINS THE OBJECTS
      orders: {
        $elemMatch: {
          placeId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId("610ae7be5867510cb43f0537"),
        },
      },
    })
```

this query only return first match, and ignore all after that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it on the server using $filter
The query bellow fitlers the orders array,and keep only the orders that
have placeId=2

Data in

```json
{
  "_id": 1,
  "orders": [
    {
      "foodId": 1,
      "placeId": 2,
      "qty": 3,
      "price": 4
    },
    {
      "foodId": 5,
      "placeId": 6,
      "qty": 7,
      "price": 8
    }
  ]
}
```

Query

```json
aggregate(
[
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "orders": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$orders",
          "as": "order",
          "cond": {
            "$eq": [
              "$$order.placeId",
              2
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Results

```json
{
  "_id": 1,
  "orders": [
    {
      "foodId": 1,
      "placeId": 2,
      "qty": 3,
      "price": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Yeah it works just fine, but please do you have an idea how can i user ```populate``` with aggregate? because when i try to use it i get an error.. aggregate(...).populate is not a function.

Comment: i dont use mongoose,but instead of populate,you can use $lookup stage i guess.
As far as i know populate does similar thing,and $lookup is faster,because all are done in 1 query.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
order = await Orders.find(...).toArray();
```

and then process the result as any array. Or is the resulting array of length one?

Comment: Yeah I know that, but it will be disadvantages to the website's performance..  @Niklas